# How to set query parameters in MySQL Query Browser?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, parameterized

Can the MySQL Query Browser set parameters of a parameterized query?  If so, how?  I tried populating the [Parameter Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/mysql-query-browser-tour-pandf-parameterbrowser.html) tab but it doesn't seem to actually set parameters when I execute the query.

I searched for quite a while in Google (e.g. [mySQL Query Browser parameterized](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22mysql+query+browser%22+parameterized)) but had no luck finding the answer.

I found [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,141743) on the mySQL forums-- sounds like I'm not the only one scratching my head here.

I'm using Version 5.1 on Windows Server 2008 (client and server), if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use parameters in Query Browser, the query has to be written like this:

```
select * from table where id=:id
```

If a parameter with the name 'id' exists in the parameter browser, the query will run.

Comment: Aha. Colons. Would never have guessed this, especially since the Connector/NET Library uses question marks for named parameters.  I'll try it out. Thanks!