# problem with mysql query when password like \/'

Tags: mysql

In mysql table name (user_login) and  i having field like login_name and password . I entered in login_name as abc and password as /'(Special symbols like \ / ') .And my query is

select password from user_login where password like '/'' and
I got sql syntax error

Answer (score 6):

You should use parameterised queries in what ever language you are implementing the call in. Beware [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack)

Comment: You don't specify which programming language you are using. Also, check the link there, it includes examples in several languages.

Answer (score 1):

you should use parameters instead of putting varibles directly into the query. i think it's aproblem with the escaping symbol.

check out this link [How to set query parameters in MySQL Query Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294974/how-to-set-query-parameters-in-mysql-query-browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you ever use LIKE in a login system you have thrown ALL SECURITY OUT THE WINDOW. Try this on your login to see what I mean:

Username: %

Password: %

ACCESS GRANTED FOR FIRST USER IN DATABASE. ( pray that isn't an admin user )

If the username is known then % as a password will give full access.

If you want a friendlier system that is not case sensitive ( yes this reduces the possible number of passwords - but is likely appropriate for usernames ) then force the case to lower ( or upper or ucwords or whatever you prefer ) - but DO NOT use the LIKE operator in ANY QUERY involving a login or unscreened user input ( such as search boxes ). Anytime you must use the LIKE operator BE SURE TO STRIP OUT OR MANUALLY ESCAPE % and _ (and if you're using MS SQL then escape all the REGEX operators too  -  []^$()*. ).

A lot of escaping functions for mysql will not escape the % _ characters, which - when used with LIKE - allows any visitor the ability to do wildcard searches ( can severely bog down the server and cause DoS issues ) and worse grant themselves undue privileges using %:% to login.